# Java thread safe, data races and good implementation

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thread-safety

I'm coding a spring controller declaring some private hashmap and updating them in some methods. Of course, I'm aware of problem of concurrent access, so I'm using the most simple way to avoid these problem: "syncronised" java thread safe capability. But I was wondering if I should synchronise my method or only the hashmap I need to thread safely update:

```
@Controller
public class myController{

private HashMap<String, String> myHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

...

//That way ?
public synchronized updateMyHashmap(){
myHashMap.add(value);
}

//or this way ?
public static void updateMyHashMap(){
synchronized(myHashMap){
myHashMap.add(value)
}
}

}
```

These methods are equivalent ? Will I have the same behavior of application ?

Comment: Any reason you're not just using ConcurrentHashMap instead?

Answer (score 3):

These methods are not equivalent.

`synchronized` on a method synchronizes on `this`, so:

```
public synchronized updateMyHashmap(){
    myHashMap.add(value);
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
public updateMyHashmap(){
    synchronized(this) {
        myHashMap.add(value);
    }
}
```

Here, `this` is the instance of `myController`. (Side-note: it's usually recommended to start class names in Java with a capital letter).

You second method is incorrect and shouldn't compile, since you're accessing a non-static member (`myHashMap`) from a static method.

Assuming it wasn't static, it would synchronize on the hashmap and not the `myController` instance.

What you want to synchronize on will almost certainly depend on what else you want to do in this synchronized block (for example, where does this `value` come from, did it have to be taken from somewhere else, and does the whole operation need to be synchronized using the `myController` instance).

I would suggest reading [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) to learn more about synchronization problems.

Answer (score 2):

If the myHashMap variable is private and only accessed via your myController methods, then you only need to synchronize the methods. To put it another way, if you synchronize your methods, they will be thread safe, but if you then directly access your myHashMap variable without using a synchronize block/method then you can subvert the lock.

To put it in even simpler terms. If you have a room with a door that allows one person in at a time then you'll only ever have one person in the room at a time... but if you put a window in the room then you can still jump into the room via the window. :)

EDIT: To elaborate. By placing synchronized on the method as a keyword your critical section will be created for the entirety of the method, that means that from that to end of the method call, nothing else will be able to run in that object. By using close blocks, you can hop in and out of critical sections as you need to. Say you had a method with 100 lines, that for 10 lines needed to use a shared resource, if you put synchronized on the method the object would be locked for the whole 100 lines of code, but if you put the lock around only the 10 lines you need, you'd only have a critical section on the 10 lines.

It's all about the situation you're in. For the example you've given there is absolutely no difference.

Comment: There is a big difference: it's not synchronizing on the same object. It may seem not to matter here, but the example is clearly incomplete, so it's hard to say.

Comment: Agreed. To answer the question succinctly, the answer is no they are not the same, in the first instance of the example you're locking the  myController object, in the 2nd you're locking the hashmap object.

Comment: In your last paragraph, I think it would be very helpful to clarify that by "nothing else will be able to run on that object" you mean "nothing else *which synchronises on the same instance object* will be able to run."  It seems to be a common beginner's mistake to think that a `synchronized` block stops *anything* else from happening, whereas it only blocks other actions which also happen in `synchronized` blocks/methods (on the same monitor).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a ConcurrentHashMap and not bother manually synchronizing access.

Making methods static won't help you much here; especially since you need an object to synchronize on, which is normally this.

Comment: If you declare a static method as `synchronized`, it synchronizes on the `Class` object for the class declaring the method.  So there's no worries about lacking a default object to synchronize on, though you're right that making the method static is in general unrelated to thread-safety issues.

Comment: @Jilles: According to java doc: "However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access"

Comment: @Zamboo: Why would you *want* that though? What are you trying to achieve that requires a lock preventing all access?

Comment: What I want to prevent is concurrent access to update things. It's true that I don't need to lock anything for read access. Is that mean that I should then use a ConcurrentHashMap ?

Comment: lock free reads are a good thing, go for it. You lock on write so that you don't have to on read.

Answer (score 0):

These two are some different things but can be used to fulfill same kind of purpose.

See here,

```
//Here you are locking your method
public synchronized updateMyHashmap(){

   System.out.println("Inside method");

   //some code

   myHashMap.add(value); 
}
```

Now in this method

```
public updateMyHashmap(){

  //Some code here

  System.out.println("Inside method")

  synchronized(this) {
      myHashMap.add(value);      
  }
}
```

So I think you can now easily see the difference between these two strategies. It depends on what you want to do and according to that you can choose any one of them.

It is more advisable to synchronized the object you want to lock.

Comment: What I want to do is "just" to have my hashmap data correctly updated: I want that when the process of hashmap update start (It could be several methods call...), then it must reach its end and then provide safety data for other threads.